# C# exception handler for account that has negative balance

Tags: c#, .net

Assignment says a property needs to validate the initial balance to ensure it's greater than 0...if it's not greater than 0...it's needs to throw an exception.

What could I use to make it throw an exception when a number is negative?

Comment: `throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();`.

Comment: but I can only use that with lists and arrays right? What could I use for a simple decimal variable?

Comment: is that a console or a winform app?

Comment: throw just ordinary `ArgumentException`

Comment: @JasonLemon - You're thinking of `IndexOutOfRangeException`. Using any exception is kind of up to you. There's nothing about the compiler that enforces it, but there are general conventions. In your case you're expecting the values within a certain range so `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` is perfectly acceptable.